# Delete from link server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-delete, linked-server, openquery

I am facing issue during delete a record from Link Server.

```
DELETE
FROM [ABC].[novasystem]..[tbl_missing_lims_ord]
WHERE lims_order_id = '1247552'
```

Error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ABC" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.21]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`tbl_missing_lims_ord` WHERE `Order_id`=? AND `collection_date`=? AND `patient_' at line 1". Msg 7345, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ABC" could not delete from table "`novasystem`.`tbl_missing_lims_ord`". There was a recoverable, provider-specific error, such as an RPC failure.

I have also used Openquery command but still error.

```
Delete openquery([ABC],'select * from tbl_missing_lims_ord where lims_order_id=1247552')
```

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ABC" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.21]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`tbl_missing_lims_ord` WHERE `Order_id`=? AND `collection_date`=? AND `patient_' at line 1".
> Msg 7345, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ABC" could not delete from table "select * from tbl_missing_lims_ord where lims_order_id=1247552". There was a recoverable, provider-specific error, such as an RPC failure.

I have checked that the RPC and RPC Out are set to TRUE on the LinkedServer’s properties.

Can anyone guide me how I can remove the error?

Comment: `DELETE FROM [ABC].[novasystem].[tbl_missing_lims_ord] WHERE lims_order_id='1247552'` ?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: @DaleK I think both tags are OK here. OP is trying to delete from a MySQL table via a Linked Server connection on SQL Server.

Comment: In that case OP should clarify, because its not obvious that that is the case.